# C++ Reversing an array not giving expected output

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to reverse an int array using pointer incrementing/decrementing. When I run it, it reverses to the halfway point in the array, and then stops and goes backwards.

This is the result that I'm currently getting:

```
Array size: 10

Original array:
   42   68   35    1   70
   25   79   59   63   65

Reversed array:
   65   63   59   79   25
   25   79   59   63   65

Expected outcome:
   65   63   59   79   25
   70    1   35   68   42
```

This is the algorithm I'm using:

```
int temp = 0;
lastElement = &data[size - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *(data) = *(lastElement);

    data++;
    lastElement--;
}
```

EDIT:

Working algorithm:

```
first = data;
last = &data[size - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
{
    int temp = *first;
    *first = *last;
    *last = temp;
    first++;
    last--;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I believe you need to stop to size/2, otherwise it reverses the reverse, returning to the original pattern

Comment: `new_size = size/2;` `if (size % 2 == 1) {new_size++;}`  `for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++)`

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you would give us every bit of code associated with the reverse algorithm and the array in question.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to reverse the array in it's own memory space. This means that when you get halfway done you start copying the data you just copied into it instead of the original array value like you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your algorithm uses pointers at beginning and end of array, so each step of the loop swaps two elements. Thus your loop should have array `size/2` steps (middle element if any stays in the current position).

```
first= data;
last = &data[size - 1];

for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)
{
    int temp = *first;
    *first = *last;
    *last = temp;
    first++;
    last--;
}
```

Comment: You are not swapping both places here so you will end with the same problem as stated by the OP.

Comment: I just noticed that - improved as well.

Comment: That still didn't work for me :(: Array size: 10

Original array:
   42   68   35    1   70
   25   79   59   63   65

Reversed array:
4729976221342183981617742416217168    0
    0    1   40  178-33686019

Comment: It works fine for me - pls see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/x6ecIg) on ideone

Comment: Just figured out why... I removed // Reset "data" to point to the beginning of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        data--; and it worked.

Comment: @SpiroMarshes Also, you should follow your own suggestion and *"Don't forget to release the memory before the program ends"*.

Answer (score 3):

If you swap half of an array for the other half, you've swapped the entire array. If you swap the first half for the second half and then swap the second half with the first half, you're back where you started. Don't do that.

Comment: So would that be two loops, one starting at 0, the other starting at size / 2?

Comment: You only need one loop, and it only has to go halfway.

Comment: My comment on Aumnayan's answer show's the output for that... could you should me an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to get familiar with `STL`, especially [STL algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/).
There is [reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/) algorithm (see linked documentation with nice example).

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop to be something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
{
  std::swap(*data, *lastElement);  

  data++;
  lastElement--;
}
```

Comment: The output for that was: Original array:
   42   68   35    1   70
   25   79   59   63   65

Reversed array:
    0    1   40  178-33686019
   65   63   59   79   25

Comment: @Bob__ My brain doesn't default to std functions, but that would be the more appropriate answer here.

Comment: That's bad ;) but please, look at [this Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182037/is-this-xor-value-swap-algorithm-still-in-use-or-useful) about the hack you used.

Comment: Thanks that was an interesting read. I wouldn't normally perform an xor swap in general for clarity reasons but I just got done watching a video on the sals20 encryption standards so my mind was on xor. ;p